# Активация игры через проверку регистрации на сайте (Patreon, UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity3d, patreon

Привет. Хочу сделать так, чтобы игра созданная на движке unity проверяла, подписан ли игрок на меня на сайте patreon.com (поддерживает ли меня данный человек финансово). Если да - открыть игроку доступ к закрытой части игры. Если нет - предложить поддержать меня финансово на сайте patreon.

На самом сайте patreon я создал скрытый текстовый пост, доступный только тем, кто поддерживает меня ежемесячными платежами.

При клике на кнопку в игре срабатывает Request.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class API : MonoBehaviour {

    private const string URL = "www.patreon.com"/*+ адрес поста доступного только подписчикам на patreon*/;
    public string responseText;

    public void Request() {

        WWW request = new WWW(URL);
        StartCoroutine(OnResponse(request));
    }

    private IEnumerator OnResponse(WWW req) {

        yield return req;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.error)) {

            Debug.Log(responseText);
        } else
        {
            print("Error Downloading: " + req.error);
        }
    }    
}
```

При выполнении этого всего в переменную responseText я получаю код страницы с постом. И всё было бы идеально... мне бы оставалось всего лишь найти совпадение части кода с текстом реального поста с помощью IndexOf. Если нет совпадения IndexOf вернёт -1 и игроку будет предложено поддержать меня финансово, или другое число, и это будет означать, что текст совпадает и игроку открывается доступ к следующей части игры.

Дело в том, что я получаю код страницы незарегистрированного пользователя (даже если у меня в данный момент откыт на компьютере браузер и я залогининен в свой аккаунт на patreon). Т.е. я получаю страницу незарегистрированного пользователя и нужный пост не виден даже у пользователей, которые поддерживают меня финансово и имеют доступ к данному посту через браузер.

Суть вопроса - возможно ли в unity (если да, то каким образом) дать возможность пользователю ввести данные аккаунта какого-либо сайта (в данном случае patreon) и использовать эти данные для авторизации на реальном сайте. (С целью - сверить конкретную страницу (авторизованного человека) с текстом секретного поста - ключа для активации продолжения игры)

Я новичок в программирований и если у вас будет решение, хотелось бы увидеть подробное описание, но в любом случае...

...Буду рад любым ответам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Дело в том, что я получаю код страницы незарегистрированного
>   пользователя (даже если у меня в данный момент откыт на компьютере
>   браузер и я залогининен в свой аккаунт на patreon). Т.е. я получаю
>   страницу незарегистрированного пользователя и нужный пост не виден
>   даже у пользователей, которые поддерживают меня финансово и имеют
>   доступ к данному посту через браузер.

Ваша авторизация в браузере вообще никак не связана с отправляемым запросом. Если вы хотите при отправке `WWW` получить пост для зарегистрированного пользователя, то в этом запросе нужно все параметры для авторизации передавать.

У патреона вообще [API](https://docs.patreon.com/#calling-the-api) есть. Используйте его.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попытался разобраться в их документации но я не знаю английский очень хорошо.
Я не нашёл у них библиотеки на языке C#, а Unity больше не поддерживает JavaScript. Могу ли я тогда воспользоваться их API?

Что мне нужно знать, чтобы уметь воспользоваться их API и получить данные из интернета?

Вы сказали что есть вариант с передачей парраметров. Как этот вариант? Где я могу прочитать о передаче парраметров?

Comment: @Pupkin это уже лучше отдельным вопросом спрашивать.